# Combine multiple MySQL UNION queries for optimization

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization, union

I have to combine these multiple UNION queries ...

```
SELECT 'Mercedes' AS marke, COUNT(autos.id) FROM autos WHERE a1=1 
UNION 
SELECT 'BMW' AS marke, COUNT(autos.id) FROM autos WHERE a2=1 
UNION 
SELECT 'Ford' AS marke, COUNT(autos.id) FROM autos WHERE a3=1
```

How can I do this with only one query?

Comment: Yes, use a CASE expression to convert the conditions in the WHERE clause to `marke` values, and then `GROUP BY marke`. _...but to be pedantic, the UNIONs are already a single query that combines queries._

Comment: The normal pattern is to say `COUNT(*)`.  Saying `COUNT(x)` has the "feature" of not counting if `x IS NULL`; this seems irrelevant for your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get rid of `UNION`s, you could use an aggregate query with a `CASE` expression to decode `marke`.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN a1 = 1 THEN 'Mercedes'
        WHEN a2 = 1 THEN 'BMW'
        WHEN a3 = 1 THEN 'Ford'
    END AS marke,
    COUNT(autos.id)
FROM autos
WHERE a1 = 1 OR a2 = 1 OR a3 = 1
GROUP BY a1, a2, a3
```

Comment: should this not be grouped by marke??    instead of group by a1,a2,a3??

Comment: @Shoaeb : this should work as it is. Can you please test the query and let me know the outcome ?

Comment: This might not be exactly the same.  Consider the case where both `a2=1` and `a3=1`.

Comment: @RickJames : ahh I think I see your point. In this case the original query would return two rows, and mine only one, right ?

Comment: @GMB - Since the OP is unclear, your result may be more 'correct' than the putative `UNION` query.